# Integral of $\int \frac{1}{x^2(x^4+1)^{3/2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to find

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2(x^4+1)^{3/2}}dx$$

I tried taking $x^4$ common but that generated $x^8$ outside which made things complicated. Putting $x^4+1=t^2$ also didn't solve the query. Can someone hint something?

Comment: It's elliptical.

Comment: @dbanet Sorry, I am not familiar with elliptical integrals.

Comment: Well, there you have it. The integral is not elementary, it's [an algebraic function of elliptics of inverse hyperbolics of algebraic functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+dx%2F%28x^2%28x^4%2B1%29^%283%2F2%29%29). Pretty messy.